# IN and NOT IN for XML column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml, xquery

I have a table with a xml column.
Xml is similar to

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <user>abc</user>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <user>vf</user>
    <Rowid>2</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <user>ert</user>
    <Rowid>3</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Maxrowid>3</Maxrowid>
</Root>
```

Now below query return sl_no column and myxmlcolumn of rows containing xml column having values 'abc' or 'xyz' in node 'user'().Below query i am using similar to IN option of sql.

```
SELECT
    [mytable].[Sl_no],
    [mytable].[myxmlcolumn]
    FROM [mydb].dbo.[mytable]
    WHERE
        [myxmlcolumn].exist('for $x in /Root/Row where (($x/user[fn:upper-case(.)=(''ABC'',''XYZ'')])) return $x') > 0
```

I want similar kind of query which does same work as sql 'NOT IN' does. That is in my case i want rows not having values 'abc' or 'xyz' in node 'user'() in xml column.
So please help me on this.

Answer (score 12):

The [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) returns a `bit`.
`1` if at least one node is found and `0` if no nodes are found (empty result set).

To get the rows where neither `ABC` or `XYZ` exist you just have to compare the result of `exist` with `0`.

```
[myxmlcolumn].exist('for $x in /Root/Row 
                     where (($x/user[fn:upper-case(.)=(''ABC'',''XYZ'')])) 
                     return $x') = 0
```

Your FLWOR query can be rewritten using a predicate on the user node instead,

```
select Sl_no,
       myxmlcolumn
from mytable
where myxmlcolumn.exist('/Root/Row/user[fn:upper-case(text()[1]) = ("ABC", "XYZ")]') = 0
```

And for the `IN` version of the query you check if `exist` returns `1` instead.

```
select Sl_no,
       myxmlcolumn
from mytable
where myxmlcolumn.exist('/Root/Row/user[fn:upper-case(text()[1]) = ("ABC", "XYZ")]') = 1
```